# Conditional media query

Tags: less

What am I missing in order to only use the media query below when `useTablet` is set to `true`?

```
@useTablet: true;
@tablet: ~"only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 959px)";

.footer{
    width: 100%;
    @media @tablet when (@useTablet = true){
        width: 768px;
    }
}
```

```
ParseError: Missing closing ')' on line 12, column 31:
11     width: 100%;
12     @media @tablet when (@use = true){
13     width: 768px;
```

Comment: Why use @ media @ tablet when (@useTablet = true) if you can just use @ media (min-width:720px) in the .footer css?

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander Because I want to control if the media query styles gets applied from a config file.

Comment: Okay, but there is no native IF/ELSE for CSS available. CSS preprocessors like SASS (and Compass) can help, but if you’re looking for more feature-specific if/else conditions you should give Modernizr a try.

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander As you can see, I tagged this with "less", and I use less syntax. It has the `when` keyword so I think this is close to working. The problem is when using it with the media query instead of a selector. I'll remove the css tag for clarity

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see that one. Not that familiar with Less but I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Less does not allow to use guards directly in media query (or any other at-rule) statements. It's not a problem though to nest media block in a guarded block and vice-versa. E.g.:

```
@use-tablet: true;
@tablet: ~"only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 959px)";

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    & when (@use-tablet) {
        @media @tablet {
            width: 768px;
        }
    }
}
```

In modern Less it's usually more practical to abstract the whole thing via mixin:

```
// usage

@use-tablet: true;

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    .tablet({
        width: 768px;
    });
}

// impl.

.tablet(@style) when (@use-tablet) {
    @media only screen 
        and (min-width: 720px) 
        and (max-width: 959px)
            {@style();}
}
```

Comment: I figured out another version using mixins, but I like your example. Thanks!